# Ubuntu 18.04 -> 22.04 Role of new _ssh shadow group vs AllowUsers?

Tags: permissions

I've moved a server that was running 18.04 to one running 22.04 and copied the following sshd_config over:

```
PermitRootLogin no 
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no 
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
AllowGroups ssh scp
Match Group scp
  PasswordAuthentication yes
```

In 22.04 there isn't an `ssh` group though, so nobody can log in. There is an `_ssh` group, but I understand that's a shadow group and users shouldn't be in it.

I've tried using AllowUsers instead, and taking users out of `_ssh` but they still get denied access.

Is this a change with 22.04 that ssh users need to be in the `_ssh` group?

EDIT: I've created a new group and added that to the AllowGroups and it works, but why doesn't AllowUsers?

Comment: Since neither AllowGroups not AllowUsers are in the default config, it's not a change in 22.04, it's a change that you made in your systems. So it's your responsibility to ensure that corresponding groups, group memberships, etc. exist.

Comment: Not sure I understand. The group `_ssh` didn't exist in Ubuntu 18.04 but does in 22.04. And when I moved my config to 22.04 nobody could log in until I put them into a group they didn't belong to before. I assume I shouldn't put them into a shadow group - or do you mean I should put them in that?

Comment: The `_ssh` group is just the `ssh` group renamed (check the changelogs). My point is that default ssh config doesn't include any AllowGroups. So if you use `AllowGroups ssh scp`, you should add the users to the `ssh` or `scp` groups, creating those groups if needed.

Comment: OK, so there has been a change to Ubuntu 22.04. I realise I have to add people to the AllowGroups, but that's not my question, which is about the role of the new shadow group in 22.04. I'll edit the title of my question to make that clearer.